# How to find a control in a TabItem

Tags: wpf

I want to find a control within a TabItem. Using FindName it is not possible. I found a way traversing the visual tree but that looks rather cumbersome. Why does FindName not do the job?

XAM:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button
        Content="Click"
        Click="Button_Click"
        />
    <TabControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="tabControl">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox
                        x:Name="textBox"
                        Text="{Binding DataContext.Message, ElementName=mainWindow}"
                        />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <TabItem Header="One" />
        <TabItem Header="Two" />
        <TabItem Header="Three" />
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl tabControl = FindName("tabControl") as TabControl;
        TextBox textBox = FindName("textBox") as TextBox;
        TabItem tabItem = tabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
        textBox = tabItem.FindName("textBox") as TextBox;
    }
}
```

"textBox" is null regardless whether searched from top or from selected tabItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextBox` is not a visual child of the `TabItem`. If you look at the visual tree, you'll see that the contents of the currently selected tab is hosted in a `ContentPresenter` that is part of the `TabControl`'s `ControlTemplate`.

This should work though:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentPresenter cp = tabControl.Template.FindName("PART_SelectedContentHost", tabControl) as ContentPresenter;
    TextBox textBox = cp.ContentTemplate.FindName("textBox", cp) as TextBox;
}
```

Comment: Thank you mm8! Works nicely.
But how reliable is it to use the name "PART_SelectedContentHost"?

Comment: @JohannesSchacht: Very reliable since it's documented. Look at the [TemplatePartAttribute] in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol?view=netcore-3.1).